# Imageview in group expandiblelistview

Tags: android

I have this LinearLayout for the group view in a expandiblelistview:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="19dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="logo"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

I would like to change the imageview based on the position of the view in the group.

For example:
Group at position 0: abc.png;
Group at position 1: def.png and so on. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own adapter, and override `getGroupView` and other methods, for example:

```
public class CustomGroupAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter { 
// other unimplemented methods...    

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_header, null);
    }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) converView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        switch(groupPosition) {
        case (0):
        // do your stuff here
        // ...    
        }
}
```